# Android Studio is syncing multiple projects at once

Tags: android-studio

I have a Kotlin Multiplatform Project which contains an android library target. That library is imported to a separate android app project:

```
// settings.gradle.kts

include ":sharedLib"
project(":sharedLib").projectDir = file("../path/to/sharedLib")
```

Whenever I sync my app project in Android studio both the app and sharedLib projects sync in parallel. I am pretty sure this is some IDE setting i fluffed up when debugging source resolution with the sharedLib a while back.

[image]

Any ideas what AS settings i might have messed up? I actually removed AS and reset the configuration and yet I am dealing with seeing dual syncing.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was some config stored in my project's .idea directory. Cleared it and everything is happy again.